# how to only allow uiscrollview when on a 3.5 inch Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working on a iOS app with a simple view (some text + photo). It looks fine
on a Iphone 5 end up screen size. But on a Iphone 4s 3.5 inch screen I need more spacing, so I want to use uiscrollview for this. But for the other screen sizes it wouldn't make sense.

How do I only use allow a user to scroll when the app is installed on a Iphone 4s.

I've found somewhat of a answer but I'm developing with Swift so I couldn't really figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `contentSize` of the scroll view to the 4 inch screen size (320 x 568, minus some pixels for the navigation & status bar), it will not allow scrolling on iPhone 5 and higher, but it *will* scroll for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scrollview in your storyboard and pin constraints to superview (top,bottom,trailing and leading).

If your content is dynamic then calculate the height of the content you want and set it as `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width,heightOfContent)]`

OR

If your content is static then put a view(lets say myView) inside the scrollview and place your static content views inside(myView) making the view(myView) height exceed the scrollview as you want. pin the view(myView) (height,width, superviewsleft,right,top,bottom).

The scrollview will become autoscroll if you have larger content on 3.5inc device and Non scrollable in bigger device.